# sending output values to a new list in python

Tags: python

I am doing a project on autonomous vehicle which travels to recommended gps coordinates. How should I create a new list and enter the output values of a program to that list? My program  is as below here, I get the line numbers which have have the string $GPRMC. I want to store the line numbers into a list and manipulate those lines further.

```
 f=open('c:\Users\RuthvikWalia\Desktop\gpsdata.txt ','r')
 req_lines=0
 for line in f:
   if(line.find('$GPRMC') >=0 ):
     print 'its here', req_lines
 req_lines += 1
 p=[]
 p= p.append(req_lines)
 print p
```

I get the output of only the numbers of lines which have $GPRMC but not the list of numbers of those lines.

Comment: Given the code as posted, you should end up with `p = [1]`. I suspect some of your indentation got messed up. In either case, you're never adding `line` to a list anywhere when it matches, so you shouldn't expect to end up with a list of the matching lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Claudiu answer is correct, just to give a small taste of what python's really like, do:

```
[(idx,line) for idx,line in enumerate(open('gpsdata.txt')) if '$GPRMC' in line]
```

Comment: oh yes, can't believe i missed that one. can give same output as mine if you use enumerate of course.

Comment: @Claudiu added enumerate, just for you :)

Answer (score 3):

This will put tuples of `(line_number, line_string)` into the list `req_lines`:

```
f = open('c:\Users\RuthvikWalia\Desktop\gpsdata.txt ','r')
req_lines = []
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if "$GPRMC" in line:
        req_lines.append((i, line))
print req_lines
```